# ¿Cómo raspar datos de mapas anidados en un mapa interactivo?

Tags: javascript, python, web, scrapy

Tengo[una página web con un mapa que contiene los distritos](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official). Puedo hacer clic en los diferentes distritos de este mapa y me lleva a los precintos del distrito. De este mapa de los precintos de un distrito dado puedo descargar el csv.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Me gustaría tenerlos a todos. ¿Cómo puedo navegar por todos los distritos del mapa con un script?

Intenté ver lo que hizo el mapa para obtener las coordenadas de los polígonos que representan el distrito, pero parece ser de un guión cuando se mira[la página de origen](http://view-source:https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148):

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.is_mobile=false;gon.is_bot=false;gon.is_ie=false;gon.no_data_text="No Data";gon.no_data_color="#CCCCCC";gon.tile_url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png";gon.openlayers_img_path="/assets/img/";gon.datatable_i18n_url="";gon.is_voters_list=false;gon.shape_path="/en/json/shape/53148/shape_type/1";gon.children_shapes_path="/en/json/custom_children_shapes/53148/shape_type/3";gon.data_path="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path_summary="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path="/en/json/custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.summary_view_type_name="summary";gon.indicator_description="District Winners";gon.event_id="2";gon.event_name="2008 Presidential";gon.map_title="Country: Georgia - Districts";gon.parent_shape_id="53148";gon.data_type="official";gon.data_type_live="live";gon.data_set_id="2";gon.data_set_id_most_recent=2;gon.history_url="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape_type/1/shape/53148/indicator_type/2/view_type/summary/custom_view/true";gon.history_id=2;gon.data_table_path="/en/data_table/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1/child_shape_type/3/indicator/null/view_type/summary/summary_view_type/summary/custom_view/true?data_set_id=2&data_type=official&ind_order_explanation=Country%3A+Georgia&indicator_type_id=2";gon.dt_highlight_shape=false;gon.indicator_menu_scale=true;gon.openlayers=true;
//]]>
</script>
...
```

Así que no puedo obtener las coordenadas del bbox del mapa al entrar y el tamaño en píxeles de la ventana para hacer una transformación de las coordenadas del mapa a píxeles en la pantalla con el fin de hacer clic en los lugares correctos en la pantalla.

Si usted va a uno de los distritos y descarga el csv, verá una solicitud de correo a `https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/download-data.csv` con muchos datos del formulario. Las 3 importantes (dinámicas) son authenticity_token, shape_id y map_title. Después de mirar a través de la url principal para cualquier momento de la información reguardando esto. Me encontré con la url: `https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official` que tiene datos json con la identificación de la forma y los nombres de todos los distritos. El token de autenticidad se encuentra en la url principal. Mientras recorro cada distrito, intento publicar la solicitud en la url de descarga de csv y guardar los datos en un archivo csv :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

shape_id_json = requests.get(
    'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official').json()

shape_ids = [district[0]['shape_values']['shape_id'] for district in shape_id_json['shape_data']]
district_names = [district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name'] for district in shape_id_json['shape_data'] if district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name']]

download_link = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/download-data.csv'
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36', 'cookie': '_Election-Map_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiJWNhNGIxOGIzYzdlYjNjMzBmNzRmZmRiMzFhNDI5MmRkBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMUE3Z3dqS1hWSzJoNmNveTJqbDVsdDJWSk5TUUFqNzh2by93SEpROU1TNEk9BjsARg%3D%3D--9f05799d877f981db5b55af9aae2925344a96323; _ga=GA1.2.1712428967.1570048706; _gid=GA1.2.498996606.1570048706; _gat_gtag_UA_108114441_2=1'}
    main_page = s.get(
        'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(main_page.text, 'html.parser')
    token = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'csrf-token'})['content']
    for district_name, shape_id in zip(district_names, shape_ids):
        print(district_name)
        r = s.post(download_link,
                   data={'map_title': f'District: {district_name} - Precincts', 'event_name': '2008 Presidential', 'event_id': 2, 'child_shape_type_id': 4, 'shape_type_id': 3, 'authenticity_token': token, 'shape_id': shape_id, 'data_set_id': 2})
        with open(f'csv\\{district_name}.csv', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

Pero para ciertos grandes distritos (como Tbilisi) obtengo un archivo del codigo fuente en lugar del archivo descargable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NGO">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Georgia Election Data</title>



        <!-- for social sites -->
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Tqdjik Receipe Data">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Tqdjik Receipe  Data brings to you the results of each receipe in Georgia since 2008. You can explore each election in detail using a variety of indicators such as turnout, overall results, individual party results, and much more. Visualizing the data using maps as well as in tabular format allows you to explore and analyze how election results are distributed geographically by district and precinct. In this way, you have the tools to explore data for different applications, such as identifying areas of low turnout to target voter mobilization efforts at the street level, where they are most effective.
...
```

Comment: Dudo que sea tarea fácil lo que comentas. Necesitarás saber las coordenadas de un punto dentro de cada polígono. Las coordenadas del bbox del mapa al entrar y el tamaño en pixeles del Window para hacer una transformación de coordenadas del mapa a pixeles en pantalla con el fin de hacer click en los lugares correctos de la pantalla.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Gracias por sus comentarios. ¿Cómo puedo obtener información de contacto de los diferentes distritos? Creo que puedo verlos haciendo que los inspeccionen, pero no los encuentro cuando abro la pagina con el código fuente.